# Horizontally align DIV elements while keeping them vertical on smaller screens

Tags: html, css

Would like to horizontally align the DIV elements (create-your-own) on larger screens while keeping it vertical on smaller screens. Was able to complete them separately but cant get it to work together

Link to my test codepen div element: https://codepen.io/Newbie1122/pen/jOqwVdP

```
<div class="create-your-own-div">
    <div class="create-your-own-wrapper">
        <div class="create-your-own">
        <header class="create-your-own-header">
            <h3 class="create-your-own-layout-pink-h3">Example example Example example Example example </h3>
            <h5><em class="create-your-own-layout-h5">Example example Example example Example example Example example </em></h5>
        </header>
      </div>
        <div class="create-your-own">
            <div class="create-your-own-tip">
                <h5 class="create-your-own-tip-h5">Tip 1</h5>
                <p class="create-your-own-tip-p">Example example Example example Example example Example example Example example Example example Example example Example example Example example </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="create-your-own">
            <div class="create-your-own-tip">
                <h5 class="create-your-own-tip-h5">Tip 2</h5>
                <p class="create-your-own-tip-p">Example example Example example Example example Example example Example example </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.create-your-own-div {
  background-color: #fbe9e9;
}

.create-your-own-wrapper{
}

.create-your-own{
  
}

.create-your-own-layout-pink-h3 {
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #c3015c !important;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: .05em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-top: 25px !important;
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}

.create-your-own-layout-h5 {
  color: #494949  !important;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: .05em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}

.create-your-own-tip-h5{
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #c3015c !important;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: .05em;
}

.create-your-own-tip-p{
  color: #494949 !important;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by *Was able to complete them separately but cant get it to work together* ? - Also what are smaller screens - mobiles, tablet what are those ?

Comment: You question is not clear! Can you add images for desired output?

Comment: @AlwaysHelping, I had extra code, I seperated the wrapper div in half, I had 2 extra divs one for the left side and one for the right, right side is what you see now essentially text, the left side was pictures. forgot what  I had but when I saw it on my test, I saw it was horizontal on pc, liked it alot so decided to delete the 50/50 split, make it just text, showing horizontal on larger screens, but now cant replicate it.

Comment: @PranavRustagi https://ibb.co/djngMvR

Comment: If you had it working separately, then just use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) to use the code at whatever breakpoint you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `display: flex` on the wrapper and then `flex-direction: row` to lay the divs horizontally. And, then, use a mediaquery with `flex-direction: column` to display them vertically on small screens. To do that you have to replace your `.create-your-own-wrapper` style with the one below. Also, you can see a demo of it working [here](https://codepen.io/frangaren/pen/mdPwOoa).

```
.create-your-own-wrapper{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .create-your-own-wrapper {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```